# Automatic mount of newly added HDD is failing - 14.04.3

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I've just put together a 14.04.3 system using an SSD as the single storage device, and it's working fine.

Now I want to add an HDD. I've used gparted to partition it, and it's formatted as ext4. It shows up on my desktop ( xfce ) as a 250GB volume, and something ( not sure what ) seems to auto-mount it on /media/. I can create a file on it. I would like it to be mounted on boot at /home/mark/data. So, I do this :

1. Create the 'data' directory, and chmod it to 777
2. Use the 'Disk' utility ( aka palimpsest I think ) to change the mount point to this directory ( no other changes made, but I have to turn 'Auto' off in the utility to be able to change the mount point ).
3. cat /etc/fstab to see that the info as shown in the Disk utility is in there ( I've rung several changes on the mount parameters, it's made no difference ).
4. Reboot

When the system comes up, it tells me that the mount has failed ( but not why ).

What could I be doing wrong, and where can I find more info about the mount failure ? Some information follows :

--- cat /etc/fstab ---

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=e7a77504-1753-4046-a492-05d4ec8bd8d2 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/2d00253e-59ed-4d70-8bad-a8dee8a074aa /home/mark/data auto nosuid,noexec,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

--- ls -l /home/mark ---

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 mark mark 4096 Oct 31 22:31 Desktop
drwxrwxrwx 2 mark mark 4096 Nov  1 16:24 data
drwxr-xr-x 2 mark mark 4096 Oct 31 22:31 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 2 mark mark 4096 Oct 31 22:31 Downloads
drwxr-xr-x 2 mark mark 4096 Oct 31 22:31 Music
drwxr-xr-x 2 mark mark 4096 Oct 31 22:31 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 2 mark mark 4096 Oct 31 22:31 Public
drwxr-xr-x 2 mark mark 4096 Oct 31 22:31 Templates
drwxr-xr-x 2 mark mark 4096 Oct 31 22:31 Videos
```

--- mount ---

```
/dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=mark)
```

Comment: Check `dmesg` output for the mount failure.  Alternatively, attempt to mount it yourself with just `sudo mount /home/mark/data` to see what mount error happens

Answer (score 1):

Thankyou Craig, thankyou Thomas W.

I think I found the source of my trouble, and it is self inflicted :(. Although I don't remember checking the box when I did the install, it appears that LVM is activated. I think this is preventing me adding a drive in the normal way.

Although several years ago I understood enough about LVM to use it properly, I don't want to use it now, because I'm concerned about the diffence in performance of the SSD vs the HDD - I don't really want to merge them into one storage pool. I shall just have to reinstall the system, and get it right this time !:(.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that mount looks at /etc/fstab and sees 2 mount points for the same device? Are you using the UUID for the HDD when entering the parameters with the Disk utility? Looking at the data put out by your "cat /etc/fstab" there is a mount with a UUID that mounts to /boot (also seems to show ext2 filesystem). If, with the disk utility, you are using the device callout (ex: /dev/sda1) to define mount parameters but there is already a mount definition for this drive in the file using UUID and mounting to /boot then you have 2 mount points for the same drive. Your options are to 1) change the mount point in the UUID callout or 2) comment out the UUID callout BEFORE running the disk utility to set up the drive. Hope this helps Craig